# «Said I» vs «I said»

Tags: word-order, quotations, subject-verb-inversion, indirect-speech

Are «said I» and «I said» interchangeable? «Said I» is pretty uncommon, or so I thought.

The sentence in question looks like so: «"It's not going to be your way," — **said I**.» Or it could be «"It's not going to be your way," — **I said**.»

Which one sounds better?

(same question for "exclaimed I" vs. "I exclaimed", etc.)

Comment: Word order doesn't matter if the person's name is used. If a pronoun is used, prefer to place it before the verb.

Comment: *"This is a strange question", said I*. Inverting the standard English *subject/verb* sequence is usually archaic/formal/literary, so obviously unless you're deliberately seeking such an effect, you should stick to the standard version. As for *"Good grief!", exclaimed I*, I suspect there might be something else involved there (it doesn't even sound "archaic" to me - just daft).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, the policeman is a completely different case. I'm asking specifically about pronouns.

Comment: @tchrist: I think you'd have to admit that word order is infinitely more likely to occur in a written narrative than in an ordinary conversation. It's quite true, as Robusto says, that the inverted sequence is much more "acceptable" when it doesn't involve a pronoun. But putting aside the trivial matter of "Which sounds better?", the issue here seems to be "Why does **said** work, but not, say, **exclaimed**?".

Comment: @Fumble Fingers  Try *When I went to the bar* from Gilbert & Sullivan's *Iolanthe* without the inversion!   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zHuap75z05o

Comment: "Said I" is simply Ye Olde way to say it, err .. for Thee to say it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In American English you would never use "Said I" but in Ireland or parts of England using conversational English it would be very common to speak in this way. I would never recommend using this formally in written documents unless you are writing some personal narrative.

Comment: I don't really think there are many dialectal speakers left who still use that inverted sequence, except somewhat facetiously. And to be honest I doubt they were ever a majority in *any* spoken dialect.

Comment: Unless you have lived in Dublin